# Change JSON structure

Tags: javascript, json

I need to change JSON struture but I'm struggling how to do it, and also I'm not sure if I need to create a new object or I can just work on the current one?
Anyway this is the JSON I want to change:

```
[
    {"document_name":"invoice_document.pdf"},
    {"Invoice Number":"18021573"}
]
```

to

```
[
    {
       "document_name":"invoice_document.pdf",
       "Invoice Number":"18021573"
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you give us an example how the conversion will look with more than 1 object in the first array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let a = [
    {"document_name":"invoice_document.pdf"},
    {"Invoice Number":"18021573"}
];

// Use reduce on `a` because we know we want 1 after this is done.
// `Acc` is short for accumulator.
a = a.reduce((acc, i) => {

  // Use Object.keys to get access to the key names.
  Object.keys(i).map((key) => {

    // Append item onto the accumulator using its key and value
    // Warning: this will overwrite any existing `acc[key]` entries of the
    // same `key` value.
    acc[key] = i[key];
  })
  return acc;

  // This last Object here is what we start with when reduce runs the first time.
}, {});
```

Yields:

`{
  "document_name": "invoice_document.pdf",
  "Invoice Number": "18021573"
}"`

Comment: Perfect, Thank You!